# Umbraco Creating Content Through Code Causes Cache Invalidation

Tags: c#, content-management-system, umbraco

We have created an area where the client can manage their content in the site instead of the admin and for some reason when we create new content the cache seems to get invalidated.

After creating the content if you go to the node in the admin you will see this error near the Link to Document property:  Oops: this document is published but is not in the cache (internal error).

Any ideas why this might be happening? Is there a way to check if the item is in the cache after creating it?

This is the method that seems to be causing the issue:

```
public static int GetOrCreateContentFolder(IContentService contentService, int userId, int parentId, string folderName, string contentTypeAlias)
    {
        var targetContentFolder = 
            contentService.GetChildren(parentId)
            .Where(c => c.Name.ToLower() == folderName.ToLower())
            .ToList();

        if (targetContentFolder.Any())
        {
            return targetContentFolder[0].Id;
        }

        var contentFolder = contentService.CreateContent(folderName, parentId, contentTypeAlias, userId);
        return contentFolder.Id;
    }
```

Comment: Are you in a load balance environment? And what version of umbraco is it?

Comment: It is not load balanced, we are hosting in Amazon on a single VM, the version is 7.1.4

Comment: Normally it happens when multiple devs share the same umbraco db. Could you show some code? And are you using the ContentService api?

Comment: Okay just posted the code that is causing the problem, we are currently using the content service api.

Comment: have you tried YOURDOMAIN/Umbraco/dialogs/republish.aspx

Comment: you mean for publishing the whole site? I haven't, do you think that this would fix the issues with the cache being out of sync right now and in the future?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you need to publish your new node called "contentFolder".

```
var contentFolder = contentService.CreateContent(folderName, parentId, contentTypeAlias, userId);
contentService.SaveAndPublish(contentFolder);
```

Use `PublishWithChildren` if you need to publish all children too.

See all methods in the ContentService here: https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Management-v6/Services/ContentService

Comment: One question I do have though, is why does that error show up in the admin near Document property: Oops: this document is published but is not in the cache (internal error)

Comment: Cool it worked :) Umbraco stores a cached version in the App_data folder on the disk. When a node is set as "published" in the database, but umbraco cant find it in the cache.. this error occurs

Comment: but why would it not be in the cache? Should it get put in the cache if it is created and not published?

Comment: When you create a new node using CreateContent(), you should save that node using contentService.Save(contentFolder) or contentService.SaveAndPublish(contentFolder) for saving and publish at the same time.

Comment: Okay so the create content call is what is leaving the cache out of sync with the database?

Comment: I understand the flow of how to create and save content now, my main concern is why the cache is getting out of sync. I just want to know if it is normal for the cache to be out of sync if I only call create content.

Comment: Umbraco only caches published content currently - read the thread here https://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/api-questions/46631-Getting-Umbraco-Content-IPublishedContent-vs-IContent-vs-Node-vs-Document?p=0

Comment: I understand that, the fact is the cache only gets invalidated if it is set to published in the database and is not in the cache. This has been happening quite a lot on our site and I'd like to know what might be causing those issues.